# Echoing Categories only if they're a child of a given category

Tags: filters, categories

I've got posts that I want to echo after the post content the categories only if they're a child of a given parent category.

#### Example:

Parent category: Goal
Child categories of "Goal": brand awareness, brand engagement

If a post is categorized, I want it to echo out those category or categories:

```
<?php
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $seperator = ' ';
    $output = '';
    if($categories)
    {
        foreach($categories as $category) 
        {
            $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$seperator;
        }
        echo trim($output, $seperator);
    }
?>
```

I'm using this, but it obviously outputs all categories, rather than just the ones that are children of the "goal" slug.

Edit: Current setup looks like this, but doesn't seem to be working. If I use the ID, it's fine:

```
<?php
        $categories = get_the_category();
        $seperator = ', ';
        $output = '<strong>GOAL:</strong> ';
        $category = get_category_by_slug('goal');
        if($categories)
        {
            foreach( $categories as $category ) 
            {
            if ( $category->parent == $category->term_id )
                $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$seperator;
        }
        echo trim($output, $seperator);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$goal = get_category_by_slug('goal');
foreach($categories as $category) 
{
    $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$seperator;
}
```

Into:

```
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    if ( $category->parent == $goal->term_id)
        $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$seperator;
}
```

Where you replace `'123'` with the ID of the Goal category.

Comment: I had posted an answer where I used `get_categories` to get all Goals children using `get_category_by_slug` to grab goals ID. I would say this is much simpler and better - except the potential pitfall of hardcoding the term_id. Usually development environments are not the production environment - so you dont know the term_id before hand. So I still would suggest using `get_category_by_slug('goal')->term_id` to retrieve the ID.

Comment: You're right. When it is a an production environment and the term ID is available, hardcoding might be better for perfomance reasons.

Comment: @eddiemoya How do I update the above code to incorporate the `get_category_by_slug('goal')->term_id` instead of the ID?

Comment: replace `'123'` in my code with `$category->term_id` and place `$category = get_category_by_slug('goal');` before the if statement.

Comment: @JasperDenkers - I added my newest code above (second snippet in my question). Doesn't seem to be working now. Did I put the if in the wrong place?

Comment: I've modified the answer to incorporate the function that gets the ID by slug. The code assumes that your Goal categories slug is simply 'goal'.

Comment: As an aside - the reason your update to your question is failing, is because you have two things names $category.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the above answer except that it should use `get_category_by_slug()` instead of hardcoded ID's. The comments got sort of confusing to follow because the question was also changed - so I've split this out into my own answer.

To work this into the bit of logic you have above...

```
<?php
    $goal_id = get_category_by_slug('goal');

    $categories = get_the_category();
    $seperator = ' ';
    $output = '';
    if($categories)
    {
        foreach($categories as $category) 
        {
            if($category->parent == $goal->term_id){
                $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$seperator;
            }
        }
        echo trim($output, $seperator);
    }
?>
```

I am assuming that the `slug` of your "Goal" category is simply `goal`.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a conditional check?

here's example which checks for parent category with ID *(4)*.

#### Example -

```
//To show child  of cat with id - 4
if($category->category_parent == '4') 
    $output .= 'foo';
```

Comment: Excuse me, you where quicker. Same solution. Btw, `$category->category_parent` is the same as `$category->parent`.

Comment: taking my words back...

Answer (score 0):

you could use get_the_category_list('',$category_id,$optional_post-ID)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list